# Sorting arrays, probably rookie mistake

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

how are u? This is the thing, ive been trying to make a btn that order an array of products by price when the user clicks on it, but its not working, and i think is my ordering function using sort, cause i dont quite get sort function already, this is what im trying to do:

```
function ordmayorPrecio(arrprod) {
    arr = arrprod.sort(function (a,b){
    let precioa = parseInt(a.cost)
    let preciob = parseInt(b.cost)

    return precioa-preciob;
})
}

function ordmenorPrecio(arrprod) {
    arr = arrprod.sort(function (a,b){
    let precioa = parseInt(a.cost)
    let preciob = parseInt(b.cost)

    return preciob-precioa;
})
}
```

This is how im trying to make the buttons functional:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
     getJSONData(PRODUCTS_URL)
    .then((result) => result.data)
    .then((productdata) => mostrarProductos(productdata));

    document.getElementById("sortDescPrice").addEventListener("click", function(){
        mostrarProductos(ordmenorPrecio(productdata));
    });

    document.getElementById("sortAscPrice").addEventListener("click",function(){
        mostrarProductos(ordmayorPrecio(productdata));
})

});
```

And this is how I try to append it to the HTML:

```
function mostrarProductos(arr){

    let productosAppend = '';

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let producto = arr[i];

        productosAppend += `
            <a href="product-info.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <img src="` + producto.imgSrc + `" alt="` + producto.description + `" class="img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                            <h4 class="mb-1">`+ producto.name +`</h4>
                            <small class="text-muted">` + producto.soldCount + ` artículos</small>
                        </div>
                            <small class="text-muted">` + producto.cost + " " + producto.currency + ` </small>
                        <p class="mb-1">` + producto.description + `</p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            `
}
    document.getElementById("produto").innerHTML = productosAppend;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sorting looks reasonable, assuming that the API returns an array of objects with a `cost` property. But you then need to return the sorted array:

```
function ordmayorPrecio(arrprod) {
    return arrprod.sort(function (a, b) {
        let precioa = parseInt(a.cost)
        let preciob = parseInt(b.cost)
        return precioa - preciob;
    })
}
function ordmenorPrecio(arrprod) {
    return arrprod.sort(function (a, b) {
        let precioa = parseInt(a.cost)
        let preciob = parseInt(b.cost)
        return preciob - precioa;
    })
}
```

The event listeners need to have a reference to the `productdata` argument from the `.then` - at the moment, they don't, they're referencing something outside instead (which may not even exist?). Add the listeners only after the response comes back.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    getJSONData(PRODUCTS_URL)
        .then((result) => result.data)
        .then((productdata) => {
            mostrarProductos(productdata);
            document.getElementById("sortDescPrice").addEventListener("click", function () {
                mostrarProductos(ordmenorPrecio(productdata));
            });
            document.getElementById("sortAscPrice").addEventListener("click", function () {
                mostrarProductos(ordmayorPrecio(productdata));
            })
        })
        .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
});
```

Comment: Man, i think i love you, thats really helpfull. The API indeeds return a cost, and ineed, productdata didnt existed outside the .then, i didnt knew then works like that, i was tryng to make a variable outside like ``` productdata = (await getJSONData(url)).data ``` but when i did that, the page just crashed :'), i think you solved it. Going to try that, thanks a lot.

Comment: A nice clean way is also using the inline compare function style since we're basically just dealing with ascending vs descending order. `arrprod.sort((a, b) => return a-b);` & `arrprod.sort((a, b) => return b-a);`

Comment: Yeah, that's a better option, `.sort((a, b) => a.cost - b.cost)` as long as the arrow functions don't confuse you

Comment: I couldn't upvote at the moment because of my level (i think i need 15 of reputation level), but i just did, it solved the problem, Im beginning to love this community and its willingness to help, thank you all. Im gonna try that arrow functions, they  actually do confuse me, but I will have to understand them at some point xd

Comment: @YasuoUy Did you do `.sort((a, b) => a.cost - b.cost)`? The other comment's `arrprod.sort((a, b) => return a-b);` won't work